# The same height of text in a large document

Tags: spacing, equations, vertical-alignment

I’m typesetting a large document that contains a lot of mathematics. The only problem is that the height of text on some pages that ends with a displayed formula is less than (about 3-6mm) the height of pages that ends normally (without displayed formula).
I want that the height of text on all of my pages is quite the same.
Does anybody know how to solve this problem? Is there any command that I should use in those pages in order to solve the problem?
By the way, I’m using options `a4paper`, `twoside` and `book` class in my document.

Comment: Are you using `\raggedbottom` by any chance? Try to explicitly set `\flushbottom` very late in your preamble and see if it changes anything. Note that `\flushbottom` is the default for `book`.

Comment: @Martin: I've tried both `\raggedbottom` and `\flushbottom`, but they don't change anything. BTW, what do you mean very late?

Comment: With "very late" I meant at the end of the preamble.

Comment: @Martin: thanks for your reply. I tried that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: contrary to what Ian Thompson said, the `\belowdisplayskip` *is* removed if it falls at a page break, so you should try providing a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is caused by the fact that a vertical space is inserted after each displayed equation. The size of this space is controlled by `\belowdisplayskip`. Have a look at section 11.5.1 of [Mathmode.pdf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf).

Unfortunately I don't know of any way to automatically remove this space if it occurs at the end of a page. I suppose you could do it manually.

Comment: There were some discussions of `\cleader` in some recent questions, which might help a little bit.